# Would a size-changing weapon property be equivalent to a +1?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

I am playing a character who will be undergoing size changes on a regular basis. I am interested in an effect which will make my primary weapon (in this case a bow) always be the correct size that I am currently (in case I end up dropping it while in a size different than natural).

I assume that this kind of ability makes the most sense as a weapon property. As much as I would like it to be a cost based ability like [adaptive](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/adaptive), but should most likely be an enhancement bonus since thats what most weapon properties are. Since keen is a +1 ability, I feel that this ability would be in-line in terms of power.

Would having adaptive size as a +1 weapon enhancement be balanced/fair? Or is it actually something that exists in Pathfinder already?

While researching this I discovered that there is a sizing weapon property in 3.5 which was a +1 bonus. Only it took a standard action for it to change size.

Comment: Why do you plan to be dropping your bow?  Are you worried about getting disarmed, or are you expecting to drop it intentionally (eg, to use a sword instead)?

Comment: I expect at some point to be disarmed

Comment: How will your character be changing size?  This is an important detail that is needed to answer the question well.  For example, *reduce/enlarge person* both change your weapon size with you.

Comment: The common way, with enlarge and reduce person. Thats why the weapon could be the wrong shape if I pick it up after or have dropped it.

Answer (score 7):

The [*Giant Hunter's Handbook*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy99s4?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Giant-Hunters-Handbook) (Jan. 2015) includes the magic weapon special ability ***resizing*** (4,000 gp; 0 lbs.) that says

> A *resizing* weapon instantly shrinks or grows to suit the size of any creature that picks it up unless it is currently wielded by another creature. It reverts to its original size 1 round after it leaves its wielder’s possession.

From what I can gather, the weapon special ability isn't limited to melee weapons. As a relatively new release, the *Handbook*'s information is likely still being readied for inclusion on [*d20PFSRD*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/).

Comment: I do not have this source material so thank you for bringing it to my attention